# Powershell (pwsh) does not take command-line arguments?

Tags: powershell-core

According to [pwsh documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7), I should be able to pass command-line arguments such as -Command or -NoExit, but these are not recognized:

```
> pwsh -NoExit
-NoExit : The term '-NoExit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
...

> pwsh -NoLogo
-NoLogo : The term '-NoLogo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
...

> pwsh -h
-h : The term '-h' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
...

> pwsh -Command "Write-host hello"
-Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
...
```

But this works:

```
> pwsh "Write-host hello"
hello
```

What is going on???

Comment: What shell are you using? `-h`, `-help`, and `-?` all bring up the `pwsh` help text for me.

Comment: This behavior happens on both the Windows cmd prompt and Powershell prompt

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, with *C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe*

Version 7.0.0 Core, just installed with msi downloaded from github :-(

**Solution** : uninstall RC version of powershell 7

I have no explanation, but although correct executable was run, it behaved like the old RC version.

I noted that installing version 7 did *not* uninstall RC, so I had to uninstall explicitly.

After the old RC version was removed, hooray, pwsh.exe honors the -NoExit and -File command line parameters on my PC ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the information you've provided I believe what you are referring to are the '-help' and '-command' arguments when using Powershell from CMD.  So for example, if you type 'Powershell -help' at a CMD prompt you'll get help text on how to run powershell commands from CMD.

To access help documentation from within Powershell, type the command 'Get-Help" (or it's alias 'help') and then the name of the command you need help on.  For example:

```
Get-Help Test-Connection
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, that's not my problem.   I've edited my original post to be more clear - on my computer the pwsh command is not recognizing any arguments.